# how to refresh a cell on a new row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

My code work fine if I have some data on the tabulator, but the "total" column doesn't refresh when i got a new row and edit cells.. I've got a "NaN" instead, but if i click on it, the data refresh. If someone can help me to refresh it for a new row, thanks. (sorry for my bad english)
here my code :

```
$("#add-row-ventilation").click(function () {
        $tabulator_ventilation_table.addRow({'date':<?= $this->year ?>}).then(function(row) {
            /*$(row.getCell("etp_accompagnement").setValue(0));
            $(row.getCell("etp_administratif").setValue(0));*/
            // TODO:si setValue(0) sur le total, il ne se refresh pas à la modification des deux autres champs
            //$(row.getCell("total").setValue(0));
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
    });

    let idVpInput = function (cell, formatterParams) {
        if (cell.getValue() !== undefined){
            return "<input type='hidden' name='ventilation_personnel[id][]' value='"+cell.getValue()+"'>";
        } else {
            return "<input type='hidden' name='ventilation_personnel[id][]' value=''>";
        }
    };

    let anneeVpInput = function (cell, formatterParams) {
        if (cell.getValue() !== undefined) {
            return "<input type='hidden' name='ventilation_personnel[date][]' value='"+cell.getValue()+"'>";
        } else {
            return "<input type='hidden' name='ventilation_personnel[date][]' value='<?= $this->year ?>'>";
        }
    }

    let totalMutator = function (value, rowData) {
        return parseInt(rowData.etp_accompagnement) + parseInt(rowData.etp_administratif);
    }

    let totalFormatter = function (cell){
        var value = cell.getValue();
        console.log(value);
        if(value !== 100){
            cell.getRow().getElement().style.color = "red";
            return value;
        } else {
            cell.getRow().getElement().style.color = "black";
            return value;
        }
    }

    /*
     * TODO:le total ne s'affiche pas correctement à l'ajout d'une nouvelle ligne
     */
    let tabulator_vp_config = {
        layout:"fitColumns",
        maxHeight: "60vh",
        reactiveData: true,
        columns:[
            {title: "id", field: "id", headerSort: false, visible:false, formatter: idVpInput},
            {title: "Date", field: "date", headerSort: true, visible:false, formatter: anneeVpInput},
            {title: "Nom", field: "nom", headerSort: true, editor:"input", validator:"required"},
            {title: "Fonction", field: "fonction", headerSort: true, editor:"input", validator:"required"},
            {title: "Catégorie", field: "categorie", headerSort: true, editor:"select", validator:"required"},
            {title: "ETP Accompagnement", field: "etp_accompagnement", headerSort: true, editor:"input", validator:["required", "max:100"], cellEdited:function (cell){
                    $.each(tableVpData, function (i) {
                        tableVpData[i].total = cell.getValue() + tableVpData[i].etp_administratif;
                    });
                }},
            {title: "ETP Administratif", field: "etp_administratif", headerSort: true, editor:"input", validator:["required", "max:100"], cellEdited:function (cell){
                    $.each(tableVpData, function (i) {
                        tableVpData[i].total = cell.getValue() + tableVpData[i].etp_accompagnement;
                    });
                }},
            {title: "Total ETP", field: "total", headerSort: true, visible:true, editor:"input", validator:["required"], mutator:totalMutator, formatter:totalFormatter},
        ],
    }

    let $tabulator_ventilation_table = new Tabulator("#ventilation_table", tabulator_vp_config);
    var tableVpData = <?= $this->ventilation_personnel ?>;
    $tabulator_ventilation_table.setData(tableVpData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you are trying to update the data directly on the row data object. instead you should be calling the `update` function on the [Row Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/components#component-row) this will set the new value and then trigger a redraw of the cells contents:

```js
cellEdited:function (cell){
    var row = cell.getRow();

    row.update({total: cell.getValue() + row.getData().etp_administratif});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry with covid i don't see your response but finally i do that :

````
            var rowCells = row.getCells().filter(function(rowCell) {
                return rowCell.getColumn().getField().charAt(0) === "M";
            });

            var effectifs = rowCells.map(cell => cell.getValue());

            var totalCell = row.getCell("moyenne");
            totalCell.setValue(getAverage(effectifs));
        } ```
and in the tabulator
``` cellEdited: function(editedCell) {
                var row = editedCell.getRow();
                setRowAverage(row);
            } ```
and for the mutator :
``` let moyenneMutator = function (value, rowData) {
            return getAverage([rowData.M0, rowData.M01, rowData.M02, rowData.M03, rowData.M04, rowData.M05, rowData.M06, rowData.M07, rowData.M08, rowData.M09, rowData.M10, rowData.M11, rowData.M12]);
        } ```

I think i will see your solution because my code is more complicated than it must be (sorry for my bad english).

thanks again.

Riwalenn
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).